# How to HTTP request for POST method with parameters - SWIFT

Tags: php, swift, mongodb, http, post

So I currently have the code below in my Button Pressed function...

- I want it to connect to my current php- API backend local database
  (using MongoDB and MAMP)
- Use the POST method
- Pass it some    parameters and get returned    some values...

Now Im not the best programmer in swift and i wanted to know what i need to add onto my code to make it work, **i keep getting the: 
 "Required parameters are missing." ERROR**

the `let postString = ""` constant are the parameters i want to pass to the method, am i doing this correctly?

The parameters i want to pass are : **name, school, email, action "addschool"** ... Doesn't matter which order :)

Thanks guys!

```
@IBAction func Rally(_ sender: Any) {
    if schoolTextField.text != nil
    {
        print("inside Rally: ", schoolTextField.text!)
        let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/index.php/api/")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        //request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "name=NAME&email=EXAMPLE@hotmail.com&school=" + schoolTextField.text! + "action=addschool"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

            guard let data = data, error == nil else
            {// check for fundamental networking error
                print("ZZZerror=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200
            {// check for http errors
                print("ZZZstatusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("ZZZresponse = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("ZZZresponseString = \(responseString)")
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the url work outside of your app? Regarding the postString format I see maybe there is a missing "&" after schoolTextField.text! and before "action=addschool"

Comment: Yes @Yarn the url does work outside the app, ill check to see if that "&" is whats missing, but for the most part is everything looking ok?

Comment: @Yarn Thanks Man! You solved it! I was missing the "&"... Cheers Guys!